# jquery accordion activate does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion

I have a `accordion` like this

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="idname1">text</h3>
    <div>
        Text TEXT text
    </div>
    <h3 id="idname2">text</h3>
    <div>
        Text TEXT text
    </div>
    <h3 id="idname3">text</h3>
    <div>
        Text TEXT text
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want the people to click a link (on the top of the page) and then that panel will open
en people will see it now every time i call my function

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    // this is to open the right pannel 
    var getal = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(getal); // i get the right name

    $("#accordion").accordion('activate', 1);
});
```

my console gives me this error

> Error: no such method 'activate' for accordion widget instance

i do not know what the problem is i have tried many different things but none worked.

Comment: You haven't told us what accordion plugin you're using. Is 'activate' a valid method?

Comment: I am starting to think someone is getting a little "downvote" happy...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you are looking to open an accordion pane programmatically. If so, you want something like this:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 1);
```

(assuming you're using the jQuery UI library)

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Note that this opens the second accordion pane, since the options accepts a 0-based integer. (0 is first, 1 is second, etc.). So just make sure you are passing the correct integer to the method call :)

The reason your code won't work is because the jQuery UI team just removed the `activate` method in v1.10 and specifically recommend using what I provided: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-activate-method-use-active-option

Comment: I got caught out by the removal of accordion methods as well - thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score -1):

Activate it like this

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
```

To just enable/disable use the methods for that purpose.

```
$("#accordion" ).accordion( "enable" );
$("#accordion" ).accordion( "disable" );
```

To access options of the accordion after first init use the options object.

```
$("#accordion").accordion( "option", "disabled", true ); // set
var x = $("#accordion").accordion( "option", "disabled"); // get
```

Look at the API http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score -2):

This should work, however, it will not animate:

```
$('.myclass').click(function () {
         // this is to open the right pannel 
         var getal = $(this).attr('id');
         alert(getal); // i get the right name

         $("#accordion").accordion('option', 'active', 1);
     });
```

The method you are trying to use WAS in 1.9.x but was removed in 1.10.x
http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active